# Objectify 4 throwing strange error in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, gae-eclipse-plugin

```
Objectify ofy = objectifyFactory.begin();
        User user= ofy.load().type(User.class).filter("userName", userName).first().now();
```

But eclipse is complaining that `The method now() is undefined for the type Ref<User>`.

I am using objectify4 with spring for a GAE project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is

```
User user= ofy.load().type(User.class).filter("userName", userName).first().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref does not have a method now(). You can see its signature here:

http://docs.objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/git/apidocs/com/googlecode/objectify/Ref.html